# Spring: Type definition error when posting a new object using a REST service

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have an object which gets two parameters through a json POST request to create a new entry in the database and I get this error:

> "Type definition error: [simple type, class
>   ffuentese.rest_example.Persona]; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `ffuentese.rest_example.Persona` (no Creators,
>   like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value
>   (no delegate- or property-based Creator) at [Source:
>   (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 3]",

This is the object:

```
@Entity
public class Persona {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;



    public Persona(String nombre, String apellido) {

        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }
    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }


}
```

This is the controller method:

```
@PostMapping(path="/persona")
public @ResponseBody String addPersona(@RequestBody Persona p) {
    personaRepository.save(p);
    return "success";

}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You'll need an empty constructor to allow for Jackson to perform it's deserialization actions correctly.

Moreover though, using the entity model as a data transfer object is not a good idea. I would suggest to create a `PersonaDto` which will contain all the fields you'll require to construct for object and the use a Spring `converter` to convert it over to a `Persona` object.

This way you'll be more flexible and you'll not be binding you transfer objects to the actual entity models.

Answer (score 5):

This could also happen if you are using `@Builder` from **lombok** but haven't defined getter/setter neither explicitly nor by `@Data` as happened in my case, reason being builder uses empty constructor to first create an empty object and then uses setter to set the properties.

Answer (score 1):

When I experienced a similar exception, I added the default constructor to the entity the exception was no more.

Comment: Use of the empty constructor is covered by the top answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Lombok. Just add:

```
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
```

With all these declared, Jackson can build all types of constructors automatically.